# Create two (or more) equal sized (if possible) interval in R using two values

Tags: r, intervals

I have a min and a max value from each football period (i.e 45, 94 for the second half).
I would like to create two (if possible) equal sized intervals, such as (45, 69) and (70, 94) where the result gets rounded to nearest integer if it is a float.

I've tried using `cut()` to no avail, and also `seq()` but I neither than can I figure out how to do.

```
frame = c(45, 94)
p2.timeslots = cut(frame, 2)
p2.ts = seq(from = frame[1], to = frame[2], by = (frame[2]-frame[1])/2)
```

```
# Output
> p2.timeslots
[1] (45,69.5] (69.5,94]
Levels: (45,69.5] (69.5,94]
> p2.ts
[1] 45.0 69.5 94.0
```

Neither did the length.out argument for `seq()` solve it for me.

Any idea how I can do this easily in R?

Answer (score 1):

The way `cut` works is that the bins are contiguous, where the left-side of each bin is typically "open" (denoted by `(`) and right-side "closed" (`]`). If you assume integers and want both ends to be closed-ends, then you need to manually control both the `breaks=` and the `labels=`, perhaps

```r
p2.seq <- seq(frame[1], frame[2], length.out = 3)
p2.seq
# [1] 45.0 69.5 94.0
p2.labels <- sprintf("[%i,%i]", c(p2.seq[1], round(p2.seq[2] + 0.9)), c(round(p2.seq[2] - 0.1), p2.seq[3]))
p2.labels
# [1] "[45,69]" "[70,94]"
cut(frame, breaks = p2.seq + c(-0.1, 0, 0.1), labels = p2.labels)
# [1] [45,69] [70,94]
# Levels: [45,69] [70,94]
```

The use of `+ c(-0.1, 0., 0.1)` can also be effected by using `breaks=p2.seq, include.lowest=TRUE`, whichever you prefer.

Comment: Thank you, I used a slight modification of the p2.labels option. Much appreciated!